# PSTricks broken in Plain TeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, pstricks, plain-tex

```
% Plain LuaTeX or Plain XeTeX
\input luaotfload.sty% comment this out for XeTeX
\input pst-circ

\pspicture(-1, 0)(3.5, 4.5)
\circledipole[labeloffset = 0](0, 3)(3, 3){V}
\coil[dipolestyle=curved](0, 1)(3, 1){}
\wire(0, 1)(0, 3)
\wire(3, 1)(3, 3)
\endpspicture
```

This produces an error message in both (XeTeX and LuaTeX):

```
Undefined control sequence.
\RequirePackage
```

When I run this example with LuaTeX and without `\input luaotfload.sty` then there are even
more errors and no picture is produced.

What is wrong here? According to the manual of PSTricks it should work with Plain TeX.

Comment: it is a bug. pstricks.tex tests with `\ifdefined\@latexerr` for the format, but as it uses `\expandafter\ifx\csname @latexerr\endcsname\relax` earlier, \@latexerr is defined and so the test is wrong. Report it to the maintainer.

Comment: Oh I was a bit slower (but longer:-) @UlrikeFischer

Comment: OK, I understand this bug. But why does it crash, when I use PSTricks in Plain LuaTeX without `\input luaotfload.sty`?

Comment: @WeißerKater it would definitely need at least `ltluatex.tex` to load `luatexbase` but it still fails, not sure if pstricks needs the font handling from luaotfload, it wouldn't be that surprising if it did, you'd need to ask Marcel I guess

Comment: It is no problem with an up-to-date TeXLive (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/generic)

Comment: The bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `pstricks.tex` which you should report.

It tests for LaTeX

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname @latexerr\endcsname\relax % do we have TeX? then @latexerr isn't defined
  \input pstricks-tex.def
\fi
```

but `\csname` defines  `\@latexerr` to be `\relax` so a later test in the same file

```
  \ifdefined\@latexerr % format is latex
    \RequirePackage{pgffor} % pgffor depends on pgfkeys
```

takes the wrong branch